# React.js how to extract out a method when two components take in the same parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components,  and  they both take in the same parameters eg.

```
<A
one={one}
two={two}
three={three}
/>

<B
one={one}
two={two}
three={three}
/>
```

I was wondering if there was some way I could extract a method out of it so that there isn't a lot of repetitive code. Some pseudocode like

```
if it's A, then <A, else, <B
one={one}
two={two}
three={three}
/>
```

Is there any way this is possible (or something similar)

Comment: Are you looking for a HOC?  https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Destructure an obhect of params. Iterate over component classes. Use a context. Use a state management system.

Comment: It may be out there but I have not seen it.  Could be tough for another programmer to pick up where you left off if it gets too complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce repetition, you can pass the same props to different components.
You can store the common props in an object first, then pass the object as props to each of the components like so

```
const sharedProps = {
  one: one,
  two: two,
  three: three
};

<A {...sharedProps} />
<B {...sharedProps} />
```

If you need to conditionally render only one of the components, then you can do something like this.

```
const ComponentToRender = conditionToRenderA ? A : B;

<ComponentToRender 
  one={one}
  two={two}
  three={three}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I’m right, something like this should work:

```js
const condition = true; // Replace this by your condition
const MyComponent = condition ? A : B;
<MyComponent {...props} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make an object that holds the parameters. Then in each of the components you can write them like this:

```
import object from 'some-file';
<A { ...object} />
<B { ...object} />
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following willman's advice on creating a HOC. My code now looks like this:

```
const AandBHOC = (Component) => (
<Component
one={one}
two={two}
three={three}
/>
```

And where I returned `<A />` I instead returned `AandBHOC(A)` (same with B)

Thanks everyone! The other answers also seem to work.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. This seems nonsensical to me--it's an unnecessary layer of abstraction (and a name that does not describe what the HOC does at *all*).

Comment: Yeah, the names are just placeholders for this particular question. In the actual code they are different, and the complexity of similarities between the two components is much more than in the example